# Sum is not getting after grouping also in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]I have a query like this.

```
select 
    TC.F_Exhibition_Code, TC.F_Exhibition,
    c.F_Customer_Code, c.F_Customer_Name,
    c.F_Address, c.F_ContactPerson,
    c.F_Phone, c.F_Fax,
    Tc.F_CreditInvoiceNo, tc.F_CreditInvoiceDate,
    TC.F_Paymentmethod, TC.F_Currency,
    TC.F_Description, TC.F_Price,
    TC.F_quanity, TC.F_ReceivedAmt, TC.F_Totalamt,
    sum(TC.F_Totalamt) as sum
from 
    T_CreditInvoice TC 
left join 
    T_Customer c on c.F_Customer_Code = tc.F_Customer_Code 
where 
    TC.F_CreditInvoiceNo = 'INV100098'
group by  
    TC.F_Exhibition_Code, TC.F_Exhibition, c.F_Customer_Code, c.F_Customer_Name,
    c.F_Address, c.F_ContactPerson, c.F_Phone, c.F_Fax,
    Tc.F_CreditInvoiceNo, tc.F_CreditInvoiceDate, TC.F_Paymentmethod,
    TC.F_Currency, TC.F_Description, TC.F_Price, 
    TC.F_quanity, TC.F_ReceivedAmt, TC.F_Totalamt
```

I trying to get sum of my `F_Totllamt` column, but I am not getting it.

What is wrong with my query?

Comment: what is the issue/error you are facing

Comment: What are you getting? what wrong with that query? And what do you want to get? how is the table structure? it has different rows with every think the same except the f_totalamt?

Comment: Simply remove TC.F_Totalamt from the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: not getting any error,but my sum column not showing sum amount,if i have 5 items in the records,i want to show sum column total amount of this item

Comment: maybe you need to use other name than sum or escape it using `

Comment: if i remove TC.F_Totalamt am getting error

Comment: Now I see, you want both current TC.F_Totalamt and SUM(TC.F_Totalamt)???

Comment: sir ,see my updated question,my sum is getting value of Total amount

Comment: @jarlh you are correct,so how i can re-write the code?

Comment: You can add a correlated query to select this sum ,(select sum(f_totalamt) from tc ...

Comment: You have to describe SUM(TC.F_Totalamt) according to what? All rows, or just for this customer, or something else.

Comment: according to this invoice no

Comment: You can use window function and write as: `sum(TC.F_Totalamt) OVER (PARTITION BY TC.F_CreditInvoiceNo ORDER BY (SELECT 1))as sum` in existing query.. hope it helps!!

Comment: showing error Incorrect syntax near 'order'.

Comment: which version of sql server are you using??

Comment: I AM USING SQL SERVR 2008

Answer (score 0):

You can use window function and write as:

`sum(TC.F_Totalamt) OVER (PARTITION BY TC.F_CreditInvoiceNo ORDER BY (SELECT 1))as sum`

in existing query.. hope it helps!!

<kbd>[Demo](http://rextester.com/QFYL99470)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

You're grouping on the variable you want to get the sum of. Hence you get the sum of every single "TC.F_Totalamt" because you're also grouping over that same variable.

Just remove "TC.F_Totalamt" from the "group by" statement and it will work.

Comment: no sir,i removed,but i am getting error F_Totalamt' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: remove "TC.F_Totalamt"  from select also.

Comment: That's because you have the variable "TC.F_Totalamt" both as a grouping variable and a aggregate (sum) variable. As suggested above: remove the variable "TC.F_Totalamt" from the select list to get the sum of "TC.F_Totalamt" grouped by the remaining variables.

Comment: sir ,so how i can re-write my query?

Comment: Remove "TC.F_Totalamt," from the select list and remove "TC.F_Totalamt" from the group by list.

Comment: that time also i am getting same out put